# Rails, Send id to URL via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a collection select, and I am trying to refresh the page, and pass the org_id to the URL when the user chooses from the collection select. The collection_select looks like this...

```
<div id="org-select">
  <%= collection_select :org, :id, Org.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

In application.js I have...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#org-select").on("change","select",function(){
      val = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
      window.location = '/sessions?org_id='+ val;
    });
});
```

When the user chooses a new org from my coll_select, I am getting a page refresh. However, my URL looks like..

```
http://localhost:3000/sessions?org_id=2
```

The org_id ($this.val()) is getting set to 2 each time. It is not being updated when I choose a new org from my drop down. The page is updating, but the id is set to 2 each time.

Here is the rendered HTML...

```
<div id="sessions">
<div id="org-select">
  <select id="org_id" name="org[id]"><option value="1">Lumbees</option>
<option value="2">Tuskarora</option></select>
</div>
```

The issue I am seeing now is that the page defaults to 'Lumbees' being selected in my dropdown, and even when I choose another value, the page redirects back to 'Lumbees'. Any ideas? Obviously there is a redirect somewhere, however there is nothing in app/views/sessions/index.html.erb that I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the page refresh was in the collection select...here is all the code...

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#org-select select").on("change",function(){
      val = $(this).val();
      window.location = '/sessions?org_id='+ val;
    });
});
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= collection_select :org, :id, Org.all, :id, :name, {:selected => params[:org_id]} %>
```

I needed to specify an object to be selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

what is your collection select id,i guess it `org_id` or write some custom id ,you are making request on change of div which is incorrect.

```
<div id="org-select">
  <%= collection_select :org, :id, Org.all, :id, :name,{},{:id=>"org_id"} %>
</div>

$("#org_id").on("change", function(){
  window.location = '/sessions?org_id='+ $(this).val()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try next:

**UPDATED**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#org-select").on("change","select",function(){
        val = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
        window.location = '/sessions?org_id='+ val;
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. I updated my question above with the results. I am getting an id now, but it get set to 2 each time I choose a new org.

Comment: can you show me inner rendered html code of <div id="org-select">?

Comment: No cigar. Same behaviour.

Comment: Hmm...still no worky. The line       val = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
seems to be correctly getting the option value, the url seems to be wrong. I am not getting a page refresh when I choose from the drop down.

Comment: I think you need one more option value (e.g <option>Any</option>) to set as default value. for now you have only two option and the default value is "Lumbees" if you are doing redirecting you can fire the change event only for second option..

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to pick an value from the `div` element which should not work.

If you listen on the `select` element insted it should work better.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#org-select select").on("change", function(){
    window.location = '/sessions?org_id='+ $(this).val()
  });
});
```

And if it still don't work you cud also try to be more precise with the selected value like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#org-select select").on("change", function(){
    window.location = '/sessions?org_id='+ $(this).find(':selected').val()
  });
});
```